# How to get data from Google spreadsheet by specific value in php?

Tags: php, excel, google-sheets

I am trying to get data from Google spreadsheet by some specific value, currently I have tried the following method:

```
 $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
 $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
 $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle(APPLICATION_GOOGLE_SPREADSHEETS_BOOK);
 $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
 $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle(APPLICATION_GOOGLE_SPREADSHEETS_SHEET);
```

It works fine when I use this:

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => "name = henryhwong", "reverse" => "true"));
```

but when it do the same for email it gives error:

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => "email = henryhwong@gmail.com", "reverse" => "true"));
```

The error is because of "@", if search anything else which doesn't contain "@" sign then it works perfectly, I am unable to find the cause behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem before. Try put email in double quotes:

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => 'email = "henryhwong@gmail.com"', "reverse" => "true"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. Hope it helps you.

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => "email" = "henryhwong@gmail.com", "reverse" => "true"));
```